# No route matches {:controller=>"devise/home", :action=>"students"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've searched for an answer to this and nothing has helped.

I have the following in my view:

```
<div id="user_nav">
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.first_name  + " " +current_user.last_name%></strong>.
  <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %> |
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> |
  <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

Which is straight from the railscast on devise. Suddenly the paths are not working anymore. (sign up or sign in) for example when I click login i get the error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/home", :action=>"students"}
```

Ive tried using `<%= link_to "Login", :controller => '/devise/sessions', :action => 'new' %>` jsut for kicks and it returns the same error.

Yes I have `devise_for :users` in my route file.

`rake routes` return all the right routes including

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
```

Any help would be awesome! I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my stack trace, something (a link) in my layout was throwing it off. I [created a custom layout](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts) for devise and everything works fine now.